# Define attributes of wget inside bash script

Tags: bash, attributes, wget

I'm trying to set up attributes to wget at the start of the program to use them for all the wget instances.

```
WGET_LOG_FILE=path/to/wget_log
USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0x'

WGET="wget -U $USER_AGENT -a $WGET_LOG_FILE --no-clobber --wait=2 --random-wait"

$WGET www.webpage.com
```

The problem is that it ignores the log and directs everything to the output or gives an error of "path/to/wget_log doesn't exist", therefore I suppose it also ignores the User agent string...

So what am I doing wrong? I've tried changing " to ' or $() ...

The weird thing is that if I execute in the terminal:

```
wget -U $USER_AGENT -a $WGET_LOG_FILE --no-clobber --wait=2 --random-wait www.webpage.com
```

It works, so I'm guessing that it's executed in some subshell and that's why it doesn't get it.

So the questions are:

1. How to correctly set attributes to wget in a bash script? Answered by Chepner
2. How to check if wget is using the user agent specified? Just wget any user agent check webpage such as: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/
3. Is 2 seconds a good wait rate to fetch webpages?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't rely on expanding a parameter into the name of the command to run and its arguments; it works as expected for simple cases, but you can run into trouble quickly. I can't exactly explain the errors you are seeing (since you aren't quoting `$USER_AGENT`, I'm surprised even your third example works).

Since you are using `bash`, you should use an array to hold your arguments, then call `wget` explicitly and expand the array to provide the arguments.

```
WGET_LOG_FILE=path/to/wget_log
USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0x'

wget_args=( "-U" "$USER_AGENT"
            "-a" "$WGET_LOG_FILE"
            "--no-clobber"
            "--wait=2"
            "--random-wait")

wget "${wget_args[@]}" www.webpage.com
```

Comment: Thanks mate for answering two of my questions, as for the third question of this thread do you know if it's a good wait time?

Comment: I don't. Depending on whose server you are downloading from, you may want to look at `--random-wait` instead, though.

Comment: As I've read random-wait multiplies from 0 to 1.5 to the value specified in wait so I guess I'm using it right. Thanks anyway

Comment: Some how I completely missed that you were already using it. Never mind then! :)